# Yii2 SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, sqlsrv, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to transfer data to MySql database by pulling data from SQL Server with Yii2. The process is successful but I am getting an error log.

Code:

```
$query = (new Query())
            ->from("tablename");

foreach ($query->batch(10000 , Yii::$app->sqlsrv) as $data) {
    $mysqlDb->createCommand()
            ->batchInsert('my_table', array_keys($data[0]),$data,['each' => true])
            ->execute();
}
```

Error Log :

> 2020-08-27 11:05:43 [error][PDOException] PDOException:
> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set.
> Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be
> retrieved. in
> /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/DataReader.php:112
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/DataReader.php(112):
> PDOStatement->fetch()
> #1 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BatchQueryResult.php(143):
> yii\db\DataReader->read()
> #2 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BatchQueryResult.php(112):
> yii\db\BatchQueryResult->fetchData()
> #3 /var/www/portal/modules/axapta/commands/DefaultController.php(122):
> yii\db\BatchQueryResult->next()
> #4 [internal function]:
> app\modules\axapta\commands\DefaultController->actionItemsStock()
> #5 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #6 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157):
> yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
> #7 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(148):
> yii\base\Controller->runAction('items-stock', Array)
> #8 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528):
> yii\console\Controller->runAction('items-stock', Array)
> #9 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180):
> yii\base\Module->runAction('axapta/items-st...', Array)
> #10 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147):
> yii\console\Application->runAction('axapta/items-st...', Array)
> #11 /var/www/portal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386):
> yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
> #12 /var/www/portal/yii(22): yii\base\Application->run()
> #13 {main}
> 2020-08-27 11:03:07 [info][application] $_GET = []
>
> ```
> $_POST = []
>
> $_FILES = []
>
> $_COOKIE = []
> ```

Comment: Try update Yii 2 - similar bug was fixed a year ago: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/17433

Comment: I am using v2.0.38 and am having this issue too.

Comment: Try update. My problem is fixed.